# specs argument in emmeans function with R

Tags: r, contrast, posthoc, emmeans

I'm trying to figure out to do posthoc test in R with `emmeans` function from `emmeans` package. However, I couldn't find out what should I put in specs argument. as far as I understand it is where I put the variables that I want to contrast (my independent variables). However, when I put my IV/IVs It gives errors. I'm putting my code and errors below:

```
X= as.factor(rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each= 50))
Y= as.factor(c("K", "L", "M"), times= 50)
Z= rnorm(150)
Model= lm(Z ~ X+Y+X:Y)
emmeans(Model, X)
```

> `error no variable named a in reference grid.

I guess specs argument is something totally different from what I think. 
I want to contrast both main effects and interaction effects. How can I do it with `emmeans` function?
Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `?emmeans`:

> spec A character vector specifying the names of the predictors over which EMMs are desired.

Your `spec` argument is `X` which contains "A", "B" and "C" (repeated 50 times). But your variables in the regression are X, Y and their interaction. You need to include something like

```
emmeans(Model, c("X", "Y"))
```

to estimate marginal means for these variables.

Short version: you are confusing the character `"X"` with the variable `X`.